# Failed to get Position Ticket

Tags: mql5

I am very new in mql5 programming and I am trying to build my first Metatrader EA, a daily previous high and low breakout Strategy EA.

Compiler shows no error.

But, when I am testing the EA, I have the following recurring error :

Failed to get position ticket

```
// Global Variables
double high=0;                      // Highest price of the last last N bars
double low=0;                       // Lowest price of the last last N bars
MqlTick currentTick, previousTick; 
CTrade trade; 

// Expert initialization function
int OnInit()
{
   // Check for User Input
   if(!CheckInputs()) { return INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT;}
   
   // Set Magic Number
   trade.SetExpertMagicNumber(InpMagicNumber);
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);

}
// Expert deinitialization function
void OnDeinit(const int reason) {}

// Expert tick function
void OnTick()
{
   // Get tick
   previousTick = currentTick;
   if(!SymbolInfoTick(_Symbol,currentTick)){Print("Failed to get the current tick"); return;}
   
   // Count Open Positions
   int cntBuy, cntSell;
   if(!CountOpenPositions(cntBuy,cntSell)){return;}
   
   // Check for buy position
   if(cntBuy==0 && high!=0 && previousTick.ask<high && currentTick.ask>=high){
      // Calculate stop loss | take profit
      double sl = InpStopLoss==0 ? 0 : currentTick.bid - InpStopLoss * _Point;
      double tp = InpTakeProfit==0 ? 0 : currentTick.bid + InpTakeProfit * _Point;
      if(!NormalizePrice(sl)){return;}
      if(!NormalizePrice(tp)){return;}
      trade.PositionOpen(_Symbol,ORDER_TYPE_BUY,InpLot,currentTick.ask,sl,tp,"Bullish Daily Breakout");
   }
   
   // Check for sell position
   if(cntSell==0 && low!=0 && previousTick.bid>low && currentTick.bid<=low){
      // Calculate stop loss | take profit
      double sl = InpStop  Loss==0 ? 0 : currentTick.bid - InpStopLoss * _Point;
      double tp = InpTakeProfit==0 ? 0 : currentTick.bid + InpTakeProfit * _Point;
      if(!NormalizePrice(sl)){return;}
      if(!NormalizePrice(tp)){return;}
      trade.PositionOpen(_Symbol,ORDER_TYPE_SELL,InpLot,currentTick.bid,sl,tp,"Bearish Daily Breakout");
   }
   
   // Calculate high | low
   high=iHigh(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,iHighest(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,MODE_HIGH,InpBars,0));
   low=iLow(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,iLowest(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,MODE_LOW,InpBars,0));
   DrawObjects();
   
}

// Functions
bool CheckInputs(){

   // Check User Input
   if(InpMagicNumber<=0){
      Alert("Wrong Inputs : Magic Number <= 0");
   }
   if(InpLot<=0){
      Alert("Wrong Inputs : Lot Size <= 0");
   }
   if(InpBars<=0){
      Alert("Wrong Inputs : Bars <= 0");
   }
   if(InpStopLoss<0){
      Alert("Wrong Inputs : Stop Loss < 0");
   }
   if(InpTakeProfit<0){
      Alert("Wrong Inputs : Take Profit < 0");
   }

   return true;

}

void DrawObjects(){

   datetime time = iTime(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,InpBars);
   
   // High
   ObjectDelete(NULL,"high");
   ObjectCreate(NULL,"high",OBJ_TREND,0,time,high,TimeCurrent(),high);
   ObjectSetInteger(NULL,"high",OBJPROP_WIDTH,2);
   ObjectSetInteger(NULL,"high",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrBlack);
   
   // Low
   ObjectDelete(NULL,"low");
   ObjectCreate(NULL,"low",OBJ_TREND,0,time,low,TimeCurrent(),low);
   ObjectSetInteger(NULL,"low",OBJPROP_WIDTH,2);
   ObjectSetInteger(NULL,"low",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrBlack);

}

// Count Open Positions
bool CountOpenPositions(int &cntBuy, int &cntSell){

    cntBuy = 0;
    cntSell = 0;
    int total = PositionsTotal();
    for(int i=total-1; 1>=0; i--){
        ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
        if(ticket<=0){Print("Failed to get position ticket"); return false;}
        if(!PositionSelectByTicket(ticket)){Print("Failed to select position"); return false;}
        long magic;
        if(!PositionGetInteger(POSITION_MAGIC,magic)){Print("Failed to get position magic number"); return false;}
        if(magic==InpMagicNumber){
            long type;
            if(!PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE,type)){Print("Failed to get position type"); return false;}
            if(type==POSITION_TYPE_BUY){cntBuy++;}
            if(type==POSITION_TYPE_SELL){cntSell++;}
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

// Normalize Price
bool NormalizePrice(double &price){

    double tickSize=0;
    if(!SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE,tickSize)){
        Print("Failed to get tick size");
        return false;
    }
    price = NormalizeDouble(MathRound(price/tickSize)*tickSize,_Digits);
    
    return true;
}

// Close Positions
bool ClosePositions(int all_buy_sell){

    int total = PositionsTotal();
    for(int i=total-1; i>=0; i--){
        ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
        if(ticket<=0){Print("Failed to get position ticket"); return false;}
        if(!PositionSelectByTicket(ticket)){Print("Failed to select position"); return false;}
        long magic;
        if(!PositionGetInteger(POSITION_MAGIC,magic)){Print("Failed to get position magic number"); return false;}
        if(magic==InpMagicNumber){
            long type;
            if(!PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE, type)){Print("Failed to get position type"); return false;}
            if(all_buy_sell==1 && type==POSITION_TYPE_SELL){continue;}
            if(all_buy_sell==2 && type==POSITION_TYPE_BUY) {continue;}
            trade.PositionClose(ticket);
            if(trade.ResultRetcode()!=TRADE_RETCODE_DONE){
                Print("Failed to close position. ticket:",
                        (string) ticket," result:",(string)trade.ResultRetcode(),":",trade.CheckResultRetcodeDescription());
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

I am stuck and would appreciate an expert advice on how to solve this issue or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Error found. Completely unexpected...
Lots were entered without decimal : 1 instead of 1.0.